# C: how to convert foreach_point(t->board) to for loop?

Tags: c#, c

I need to separate values with a comma in each case but the last.
Various posts suggest to use `for` instead of `foreach`, 
but as this is a patch, and I don't use C, how can I convert 
`foreach_point(t->board)`  to a `for` loop?

Comment: Is this question intended to clarify previous posts?  Which ones?  Can you provide a little more detail to better enable the community to help you?

Answer (score 1):

It's basically the same syntax as a for-loop in C#:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++)
{
    t->board[i] ...
}
```

You will need to know `NUM_ELEMENTS`, obviously!

Comment: @peepo: If `t->board` is a pointer to some allocated memory (i.e. a "dynamic" array), then no.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `foreach_point` does, but if I guessed correctly, I usually do something like:

```
printf("%d", t_board[0]);            /* print the 1st element */
for (k = 1; k < NUM_ELEMENTS; k++) { /* notice `k = 1`, not the usual `k = 0` */
    printf(", %d", t_board[k]);
}
puts("");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually answerable.

[CCAN](http://ccan.ozlabs.org) (think CPAN, but for C) [does have a foreach module](http://ccan.ozlabs.org/info/foreach.html) that would probably work for you. Note, Rusty Russel (one of the chief Linux kernel hackers) maintains CCAN, these links are highly unlikely to vanish in the future.

Here's the implementation (directly from the link, this is a trivial example):

```
// Figure out how to get usage: message out of a program.
    #include <ccan/foreach/foreach.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <err.h>

    // Returns true if program outputs "usage:"
    static bool try_usage(const char *prog, const char *arg)
    {
        char *command;
        FILE *in;
        int status;

        command = malloc(strlen(prog) + 1 + strlen(arg) + 1 +
                 sizeof("</dev/null 2>&1 | grep -qiw usage:"));
        sprintf(command, "%s %s </dev/null 2>&1 | grep -qiw usage:",
            prog, arg);
        in = popen(command, "r");
        if (!in)
            err(2, "running '%s'", command);
        status = pclose(in);
        free(command);
        return (WIFEXITED(status) && WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0);
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        const char *arg;

        if (argc != 2)
            errx(1, "Usage: %s <progname>\n"
                 "Figures out how to get usage message", argv[0]);
        foreach_ptr(arg, "--help", "-h", "--usage", "-?", "") {
            if (try_usage(argv[1], arg)) {
                printf("%s %s\n", argv[1], arg);
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        printf("%s is unhelpful\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
```

With a little work, this should *probably* do what you want.